# How to import a file from root project in nuxt-module?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I'm developing a `nuxt-module`, but I'm with a question:

How to import a file for example:  `file.config.js`, that will be in the same folder position as `nuxt.config.js`.

The main idea is to import components on this `file.config.js` and be able to use it on as replacements from to the default components on my `nuxt-module`.

I want to do that because when I import `vue components` on my `nuxt.config.js` to send as properties to `nuxt-module` didn't works (error bellow):

Has someone a hint how to do that?

```sh
 FATAL  Unexpected token '<'                                                                                               16:27:12

  <template>
  ^
  
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
  at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
  at g (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:54280)
  at src/pageeditor/modules/index.js:1:199
  at g (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:55111)
```

Comment: please check the response on your network developer tab - could you please tell us if your response is HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for this problem.

It's not possible to import `vue components` on the build, so I use the `addTemplate` from the `nuxt-modules`.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/internals-module-container/#addtemplate-template

With that I could add the necessary files to the `nuxt-module` that I'm working on, and use this files on my `vue-components`.